# How to make FLATTEN function in Snowflake return PATH in Dot Notation instead of Brackets Notation

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, dot-notation

When using FLATTEN function in Snowflake, we use the values in the PATH column, to dynamically construct a SELECT clause to query the semi-structured (JSON) column in the data table.

We concatenate:

```
<variant_col>:<value_in_path_column>,
```

This means we assume the values in the PATH column are to be used with the Dot Notation (as described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured#dot-notation))

We encountered a rare scenario, where the field key inside the variant column conatains a dot (.) in it, for example:

```
{
    "0.text": "some_string_value",
    "legal_name": "other_string_value"
}
```

In this case, after running the FLATTEN function, we get the following output:

| VARIANT_COL | SEQ | KEY | PATH | INDEX | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| { "0.text": "foo", "legal_name": "bar" } | 1 | 0.text | ['0.text'] |  | "foo" |
| { "0.text": "foo", "legal_name": "bar" } | 1 | legal_name | legal_name |  | "bar" |

We expect the value in the PATH column to be `"0.text"` instead of `['0.text']`

Is there a way to force it into a Dot Notation?

*EDIT:the current solution is to edit the code, so if we encounter this case, we will explicitly edit it. But it is a workaround to something that looks like an inconsistent behavior of Snowflake. I will also create a support ticket.

Thanks

Code to recreate the issue:

```
create temp table notation_issue
as select parse_json($${"0.text": "foo", "legal_name": "bar"}$$) as variant_col;

create temp table flatten_results as 
select * 
  from notation_issue,
       lateral flatten(variant_col, recursive=>True);

select 'select ' || listagg('variant_col:' || path, ',\n') || ' from notation_issue'
from flatten_results
;
/* This raises an error */
select variant_col:['0.text'], variant_col:legal_name from notation_issue;

/* This does not raise an error */
select variant_col['0.text'], variant_col:legal_name from notation_issue;

/* This also does not raise an error */
select variant_col:"0.text", variant_col:legal_name from notation_issue;
```

Comment: So you have an attribute name that wouldn't be allowed as a column name in SQL without the double-quotes (which is why your 3rd option above works.  Might it be better to try and replace/rename the attribute or just use the 3rd option above?

Comment: How about using key and not path like select 'select ' || listagg('variant_col:"' || key ||'"', ',\n') || ' from notation_issue'
from flatten_results;